# Intermittent delay sending MSMQ message across network

Tags: performance, msmq

I'm experiencing an intermittent problem when sending an MSMQ message from one server to another, where the message is sent from one service, but is not received by the consumer for up to 30 minutes.

Turning on end-to-end logging (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc730882(v=ws.11)), I was able to narrow it down to the sending server.

The messages are being put in the outgoing queue, but not being sent over the network for up to 30 minutes in some cases.

As an example, I can see a message being placed on the outgoing queue at 13:35:23. The next log is at 13:39:47 with "Message sent over network".

However I have instances of the same message types being sent to and from the same servers, taking less than a second. Also, messages sent between queues on the same server have not had issues.

Anyone have any ideas of what could be causing the delay, or how I could track it down?

Comment: I would look at a network trace to se if the sender is having trouble connecting to the listening port on the destination. What's the status of the outgoing queue?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions John. I'll take a look and let you know what I find.